# Ionic 7 capacitor 5 internet access does not work

Tags: ionic-framework, android-permissions, capacitor, ionic7

Ionic 7 internet access does not work. But `status.connected` (@capacitor/network) says true. I think android deny the connection.

**package.json** part:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "5.0.5",
    "@capacitor/network": "^5.0.6",
    "@ionic/angular": "^7.1.0"
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** part:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

  <application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**main.ts** part:

```js
import {ConnectionStatus, Network} from '@capacitor/network';

export const networkStatus: ConnectionStatus = {
  connected: false,
  connectionType: 'none'
};

/**
 * ERROR: event does not fire
 */
Network.addListener('networkStatusChange', status => {
  networkStatus.connected = status.connected;
  networkStatus.connectionType = status.connectionType;
});
```

**app.component.ts** part:

```js
import {Network} from '@capacitor/network';
import {networkStatus} from '../main';

export class AppComponent {
    async refreshNetworkStatus() {
        const status = await Network.getStatus();
        this.netStat.connected = status.connected;
        this.netStat.connectionType = status.connectionType;
    }
}
```

The first problem is `Network.addListener('networkStatusChange')` (main.ts) does not fire. In the **app.component.ts** the function `refreshNetworkStatus()` works and show me status=true and type=wifi. So, it looks good. But I can't access anything on the network.

Why can't I access the Internet?

When installing the app, Android does not ask whether it can access the Internet. I think Android should ask because I say in the AndroidManifest.xml that I want.

Why doesn't Android ask for the right to access the Internet?

**test devices**

- Motorola Moto G22 - Android 12
- Fairphone 4 5G - Android 13
- Google Pixel 5 - Android 11
- Asus ZenFone 3 - Android 8

Answer (score 0):

My mistake is somewhere else. With the above configuration, Internet access works in Android.

Comment: Answers (and questions) should be written such that future users can learn from them, too. Please either [edit] this answer to provide details about what was wrong, or consider deleting your question entirely (I think you'll have to delete this answer first).